# Understanding python program

Tags: python

I came across a python program question. Below is the question and its corresponding solution.
I just could not understand the flow of the program. Especially the `@person_lister`, and its significance.

Also, `print(*name_format(people), sep='\n')` name_format here is taking 2D array instead of 1D.
As per the definition of name_format it possibly expects a 1D array.

Can someone please explain me the flow of this program I just cannot understand it.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

**Question**
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/decorators-2-name-directory/problem

**Solution:**

```
import operator

people = [input().split() for i in range(int(input()))]

def person_lister(f):
    def inner(people):
        return [f(person) for person in sorted(people, key=operator.itemgetter(2))]
    return inner

@person_lister
def name_format(person):
    return ("Mr. " if person[3] == "M" else "Ms. ") + person[0] + " " + person[1]

print(*name_format(people), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators)

Comment: The short answer is that `person_lister()` changes `name_format()` into `inner()` - calling `name_format()` on each of the sublists in `person`, all in turn.